# Correct query for jsonb_path contained in array

Tags: sql, postgresql, path, jsonb

Table

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    username   VARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
    info       JSONB
);
INSERT INTO users (username, info)
VALUES 
('Lana', '[
  {
    "id": "first"
  },
  {
    "id": "second"
  }
]'),
('Andy', '[
  {
     "id": "first"
  },
  {
      "id": "third"
  }
 ]');
```

So I want to find all users, whose `info.id` contained in array like ["first"].

request should be like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
where jsonb_path_exists(info, '$.id ? (@ in ("first", "second", "third",...) )');
```

But I can't find the correct implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the array elements using `$[*]` then use `==`

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
where jsonb_path_exists(info, '$[*] ? (@.id == "first" || @.id == "second" || @.id == "third")');
```

Or maybe collect all IDs and use the `?|`  operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
where jsonb_path_query_array(info, '$[*].id') ?|  array['first','second','third');
```

That would return rows that contain *at least* one of those values.

If you need to find rows that contain all values, use `?&` instead.

Comment: I can, but I need to check for content in an array. (corrected description)

Comment: You can use an OR condition

Answer (score 2):

There is no `IN` operator in the SQL/JSON Path language. If you want to find one of many alternatives, use a regex, e.g.

```sql
select * 
from users 
where jsonb_path_exists(info, '$.id ? (@ like_regex "^(second|third)$" )');
```